# Detect a commented line in a linux bash script from another linux script using grep

Tags: linux, string, bash, grep

I have a script in linux (`script A`) that usually contains the following command:

```
/usr/bin/do-some-test
```

I am creating a bash script now (`script B`), to always check if (`script A`) includes the above command.

so i used this:

```
if grep /usr/bin/do-some-test "script A"; then
    echo "All good"
else
    echo "Script A file is not updated!"
```

the problem is, that if i comment the command in (`scriptA`), like this:

```
#/usr/bin/do-some-test
```

the result of the grep search is still `TRUE`.

how can i search for `#/usr/bin/do-some-test` but make sure it doesn't have the `#` in the beginning?

Comment: One possibility is `grep "^/usr/bin/do-some-test"` i.e. test that the line starts with this and nothing else.

Comment: btw, when you said, `remark`, you wanted to say, `comment`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use anchors in your regex:

```
if grep -Eq '^ */usr/bin/do-some-test' "script A"; then
   echo "All good"
else
   echo "Script A file is not updated!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch preceding tabs one should write the funny-looking

```
grep -E '^['$'\t'' ]*command'
```

which is constructed from two single-quoted strings with a `$'\t'` in the middle (and contains a space before the closing bracket), or better  use a Posix character class whose intent is clear:

```
grep -E '^[[:space:]]*command'
```